# Finding work using integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

So I have the following exercise:

Find the work that is necessary to pump empty the cylindrical motor oil tank, it the tank is placed up on the base. The height of the tank is 202cm, radius of the bottom is 88cm and the specific weight of the motor oil is 0.92

Take  $ 9.8m/s^2 $ as the acceleration of gravity and $ 1000kg/m^3  $ as the density of the water.

I have to find

1) the weight of the motor oil (N/m^3) K=

2) indifferent integral to find the work F(x)=... +C

3) the work in joulses W=

What I have found out:

$$ V=1564288 \pi cm^3 $$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.